# checking if an Int is in a BST Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to design a function in haskell to check if a Binary Search Tree contains an integer, and if it does the function will return the bool 'True'. Since I'm dealing with BST's, I have a pretty good idea of how to complete this function, but am having trouble when dealing with the passed in integer. My current outline looks like this:

```
insideBST :: Int -> Tree -> Bool       --function receives input Int, and a tree, returns bool
insideBST (i Leaf i) = True   --base case, if function receives leaf whose int matches what was passed in to function, return True.
insideBST (i Node h l r) = if i > r then insideBST(i r)   --if i > root, inBST(r)
                       else if i < r then insideBST(i l)   --if i < root, insideBST(l)
```

But I'm having trouble with the second line determining (i leaf i), my intention was to check if the int received in this function is the same as the int of the leaf, and if so return True. But I'm getting a Parse error in pattern: i,

How do I write this correctly? checking if the int received matches the int of the leaf

------------- EDIT --------------

After some great help I've fixed the glaring errors in my original code:

```
insideBST i (Leaf z) = i == z              -- if leaf i value = int i recieved, return True
insideBST i (Node h l r) = if h.value > i then insideBST i l else if h.value < i then insideBST i r
```

Now my question is with my last line, I want it so that if the Int value of head  is greater than the i Int value, it will call the insideBST function for the left subtree, else if head is not greater than i, it will call the right subtree. This code gives me an parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Is it something with my long if statement? Maybe that isnt formatted correctly

This is my tree declaration:

data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf Int
  deriving (Eq,Show)

Comment: Why do you use parenthesis that way? Pattern matching is also linear: you can not use the same variable name twice in the head of a function.

Comment: Your second `if` in the node case is missing an `else`.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specifically about the recursive call line now

Comment: `h` is an `Int`, and you can compare that directly -- replace `h.value` with `h`. Remember that every `if` needs an `else`: you have to handle the "equal" case on `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few syntactic errors in your function definition and one semantic issue.  From the top, you said:

```
insideBST (i Leaf i) = True
```

This pattern makes no sense. When you have a function with separate arguments you don't combine them inside a single parenthetical.  The fixed syntax is:

```
insideBST i (Leaf i) = True
```

... But the semantics is wrong.  You can't bind `i` to two different values - it does not mean "these two values are the same" as in prolog like languages.  Instead:

```
insideBST i (Leaf l) = i == l
```

The same syntactic fix can be done for the `Node` line of `insideBST`, but you also need to fix that to use the same function name - you seemed to have switched to `inBST`, now we have:

```
insideBST i (Node h l r) = ...
```

Finally, your function application is just a space and not parenthesis like you've used.  As a result `inBST (i r)` is parsed as applying the function `i` to the argument `r` then applying the function `inBST` to that result.   Use `insideBST i r`.

Comment: Thank you, I've gotten the insideBST i (Leaf z) = i == z line working , and I reformated my third line to look like :    insideBST i (Node h l r) = if i > r then inBST i r                But now that third line returns a " parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)  " . Is there some indentation for an if statement I'm missing?

Comment: oh wait well for one my r value is a tree not an Int

Comment: okay so for a line like this:   "     insideBST i (Node h l r) = if h.value > i then insideBST i l else if h.value < i then insideBST i r         "   is it possible to get the int value for the head simply like that? I know of course you can't do h.value in haskell, thats just to show the effect I'd like to obtain

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specifically about this line now

Comment: I can't help you with that part, you didn't show your data declaration.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question to show the declaration

Comment: So `h` is an `Int` not some product type.  Just use `h` instead of `h.value`.

Comment: okay, Im still getting an " parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) " error. My code is:   https://justpaste.it/1g0eh     [ sorry for other site link, just wanted to paste it somewhere so you could see the formatting of indentations ]

Comment: edit: nvm, I looked online and realized I was missing my last else statement. everything works now. thank you so much for your help